# How to bind and update a list view Item to a RequestBin http page

Tags: c#, listview, callback, twilio, twilio-api

I'm developing a graphic user interface where the user can send a message to mutuple user using Twilio API in c#

I'm trying to bind a list view to the status of each number being sent and I also want to know the status of the message every time the user click on refresh list view

```
 public void sendSMS(string ssid, string token , string fromNumber, List<string>TOnumbersList ,string msgBody )
    {
       TwilioClient.Init(ssid, token);

        foreach (var toNumber in TOnumbersList)
        {
         var message = MessageResource.Create(
         to: new PhoneNumber(toNumber),
         from: new PhoneNumber(fromNumber),
         body: msgBody,
         provideFeedback: true,
         statusCallback: new Uri("http://requestb.in/1jnk4451"));


            ListViewItem items = new ListViewItem(message.To);//This show the number being sent to ( delivered number)
            items.SubItems.Add(message.Status.ToString()); //Refresh the status WHERE number = message.To 
            items.SubItems.Add(message.ErrorCode.ToString());//Show error code in case 
            items.SubItems.Add(message.ErrorMessage); // In case error message show them 
            listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { items });

        }


    }
```

Twilio API is doing the perfect job updating the status so everytime I go click the link I can see the status. as explained in this documentation [Track Delivery Status of Messages in C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/sms/how-to-confirm-delivery-in-csharp#receive-status-events-in-your-web-application)

But is It possible to bind a list view so it can be updated everytime the user click on refresh list view ?

Or what is the best way to dynamically show the message status from the URI http://requestb.in/1jnk4451? Maybe embedding a webpage would be better ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Rather than using the RequestBin URL, if you provide a URL to your own application then you can write an endpoint that receives the [status updates of the messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#status-callback-parameter-request-parameters). That way you can store the status yourself and update the list view without having to loop through all the messages.

**[Edit]** In more detail:

When you [send an SMS message with Twilio using the REST API](http://twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) you can set a [`statusCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional) to receive updates about the message as it processes through from Twilio to the network and the device.

Twilio will make HTTP requests to this URL as the message goes through each state, the possible states being queued, failed, sent, delivered, or undelivered. Twilio sends a number of parameters as part of this request, some are [general ones about the message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters) and some are about the [actual status](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#status-callback-parameter-request-parameters).

To receive these requests you need to set up a web server. I'm not a C# developer I'm afraid, however we have a guide on how to set up a [C# and ASP.NET MVC environment](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-set-up-your-csharp-and-asp-net-mvc-development-environment) that can receive webhooks that should be able to help you there.

Let me know if this helps a bit more!

Comment: I really appreciate your time replying to my message , would you mind redirecting me or simply mentioning few keyword that could help me understanding how to provide my own URL? and what tools can I use to read from that URL ? I would really appreciate

Comment: Hey, no worries, I updated the answer with some more detail and links.